# Cloud Translation API translate URL in Android

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, android-webview, google-translate

I'm shuffling documentation of **Google Cloud Translation API** and I'm confused about something. I need to translate whole website content (prefably in webview), not text. [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#client-libraries-usage-java) refers to text translation (**following code snippet**) but how to translate single web URL in **Android**? I couldn't find any reference for that. Thanks in advance.

```
String url = "https://tr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google";
Translate translate = TranslateOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
                        Translation translation = translate.translate(url, Translate.TranslateOption.sourceLanguage("tr"), Translate.TranslateOption.targetLanguage(deviceLanguage));
                        System.out.printf("Translation: %s%n", translation.getTranslatedText());
```

[Google Translate](https://translate.google.com) can able to do that but I'm not sure how to do that with API? Code snippet doesn't translate Website content, it try to translate string only.

Answer (score 0):

The Cloud Translation API is not meant to translate a whole website content. As per this [link](https://cloud.google.com/translate/) it is a *dynamic translation of source text from the source language to a target language (such as French to English and vice-versa). Language detection is also available in cases where the source language is unknown.*

Answer (score 0):

Apperantly there is no integrated website translator in Cloud Translation API. However, if anyone want to translate dynamic website here is the solution:

```
https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?sl=ORIGINALLANGUAGE&tl=TRANSLATEDLANGUAGE&u=WEBSITEURL
```